# linux voip library

Tags: c++, linux, voip

Can someone suggest free VoIP library(C/C++) for Linux? All libs that I found are outdated and won't compile on my Ubuntu 12.10 box. I have tried OPAL, Sofia, PJ - can't get working anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've gotten PJ to compile and run on Ubuntu 10.04 and 12.04 (32 bit).  Also Linphone and GStreamer.  I'm guessing your environment needs a clean-up or some additional stuff in it.  Liknphone, in particular, took several upgrades with bleeding edge packages.

So, please pick one and compile it and tell us what happens.  The configure script's log might be a good thing to attach to your reply.  Perhaps, also, the output of the make you run after configure,

Comment: By Linkphone did you mean linphone? I've tried to compile it and was given this:
<code>
......
videoenc.c: In function ‘prepare_h263’:
videoenc.c:303:13: error: ‘CODEC_FLAG_H263P_UMV’ undeclared (first use in this function)
videoenc.c:303:13: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
videoenc.c:305:13: error: ‘CODEC_FLAG_H263P_SLICE_STRUCT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
......
</code>
Do you have any ideas how can I fix this? I have googled and didn't find any answer.

Comment: At the end I managed to build PJ. All I needed is to update some packages. Thanks for your suggestion.